# Why can I shake all the bushes and trees?

Tags: stardew-valley

During special times when there are berries growing on bushes, I see why you'd need that ability. But the rest of the time you can still shake everything. I've been shaking stuff for a bit at the beginning but nothing seemed to happen, so I stopped. Is this just a neat mechanic simply for vanity, or does something happen if you shake the right plant or enough times?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shaking trees will drop a seed if the tree has any that day, or fruit if it is a fruit tree. Similarly, shaking bushes will drop berries if the bush has any that day. Other than that, no, there is no reason to go beat around the bush.

Comment: Shaking trees can be useful early game when energy is at a premium and you usually have a bunch of free time and no energy at the end of a day. Shaking trees doesn't require energy, and it potentially nets seeds which can be made into energy bars allowing you to pack more into your first few days activity.